# "Приспосабливаемость" или "приспособляемость"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приспособляемость - согласно словарю.

Comment: И приспосабливаемость - согласно словарю.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке существуют оба этих слова:
***ПРИСПОСОБЛЯ́ЕМОСТЬ***, и, мн. нет, ж. (книжн.).
Способность быть использованным, приспособленным.П. электрической энергии к бытовым нуждам.||Умение или способность приспособиться, примениться к окружающим условиям.П. организмов к среде.
Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь Ушакова, 1935-1940
Орфография и орфоэпия
приспособля́емость, -и
Яндекс.Словари › Орфографический словарь, 2004
приспособл/я́/ем/ость/
Яндекс.Словари › Морфемно-орфографический словарь, 2002

***ПРИСПОСАБЛИВАЕМОСТЬ***
ПРИСПОСОБЛЯ́ЕМОСТЬ, -и и ПРИСПОСА́БЛИВАЕМОСТЬ, -и, ж. (спец.). Способность или возможность приспособиться к чему-н. П. организмов к среде.

Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.